# Assign a function return value to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have created a function that returns a variable.

```
function randomZone(){
  return x;
}
```

I want y to equal the function return value such that y=x;

```
y=randomZone();
```

I've read that this sets the variable equal to the function instead and that I have to put (); at the end of the function to invoke it first. Which way is correct?

```
y=randomZone()();
y=(randomZone())();
```

Also, how would you call it when you are invoking inside of another function? For example:

```
document.getElementById(randomZone()).classList.add('someClass');
document.getElementById(randomZone()()).classList.add('someClass');
document.getElementById((randomZone())()).classList.add('someClass');
document.getElementById((randomZone())();).classList.add('someClass');
```

Which way is correct? Wouldn't you also not include the semi-colon because that would terminate the code early?

Comment: `y = randomZone` would assign `y` the function. 
`y = randomZone()` invokes the function first and assigns its return value to `y`.

Comment: If `x` is not a function, this is the valid: `document.getElementById(randomZone()).classList.add('someClass');`

Comment: `y=randomZone();` is correct. y is being assigned whatever the execution of randomZone returns.

Comment: Is `x` (the return value of `randomZone` a function? If not, calling it doesn't make sense: if `randomZone` returns `5`, you wouldn't call `5()` and neither would you call `randomZone()()`

Comment: `randomZone()()` and `(randomZone())()` are equivalent (but, as the other comments already suggested, likely both wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `y=randomZone;` assigns the function itself to the variable `y`, now you can call the function by doing `y()`
- `y=randomZone();` assigns the return of the function to `y`, now `y` is equals to `x` (the return of the function) when this code is executed by any other script
- and using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) you can do eny of this instantly when the script is loaded:

`( function() { y=randomZone(); //code inside these brackets is executed instantly } ());`

Comment: Thanks, I had initially done that although was getting really confused by other threads I had read.

Comment: You're welcome, @BrianBrain!  Please, consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer for future reference ;)